# In which controller will action builder executes

Tags: scala, playframework

I have Action builder

```
  class LoggingAction @Inject()(parser: BodyParsers.Default)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends ActionBuilderImpl(parser) {
     override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {
        Logger.info(s"Controller = ${},  " +
            s"method = ${request.method},  " +
            s"URI = ${request.uri},  " +
            s"remote-address = ${request.remoteAddress},  " +
            s"domain = ${request.domain}")
       block(request)
    }
   }
  }
```

And I have some simple routes, one of them

```
...
def index() = loggingAction { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
Ok(views.html.index())
}
...
```

How to log that LoggingAction is executed in this controller within LogginAction

Comment: Take a look at [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaLogging#logging-patterns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the signature of `LoggingAction` to pass the current class.

```
 class LoggingAction @Inject() (controller: AbstractController)(parser: BodyParsers.Default)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends ActionBuilderImpl(parser) {
     override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {
        Logger.info(s"Controller = ${controller.getClass.getName},  " +
            s"method = ${request.method},  " +
            s"URI = ${request.uri},  " +
            s"remote-address = ${request.remoteAddress},  " +
            s"domain = ${request.domain}")
       block(request)
    }
   }
```

and then create an instance of the logging action specifically for your controller (this can be made easier by creating a Guice factory for it)

```
class TestController @Inject() (cc: ControllerComponents, parser: BodyParsers.Default)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
  extends AbstractController(cc) {

  lazy val loggingAction = new LoggingAction(this, parser)

  def index ()= loggingAction { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.index())
  }
}
```